# Laradock 404 not found nginx

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx, laradock

I'm trying to set up Laradock for my Laravel projects. I started with a new laravel project just to test things before trying with my current projects.
I followed the tutorial but somewhere during the steps I must have messed something up I think because when I surf to the URL I get a "404 not found nginx". Someone experienced this before or knows what might be wrong? Thanks in advance!

[404 error in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xa2kE.png)

**My example.conf in /var/wwwlaradock/nginx/sites**

```
server {

listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

server_name example.local;
root /var/www/example/public;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;
    fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}

location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    root /var/www/letsencrypt/;
    log_not_found off;
}

error_log /var/log/nginx/laravel_error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/laravel_access.log;
}
```

**My hosts file**

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1   example.local
```

The name of my laravel project is "example" and is located in **/var/www**

Comment: Which url you are trying ? `localhost` or `example.local`

Comment: both give the same error

Comment: Can you try removing `127.0.0.1   localhost` in hosts file & test with `example.local`

Comment: Just tried it, same result :/

Comment: because you are using laradock you can do ```docker-compose exec workspace bash``` and then browse to ```/www/example/``` now check what's in there with ```ls``` or ```ll```. Open up docker-compose.yml to see which directories you've mapped to the docker container

Comment: Hey, Førsitter. Were you able to fix this? I am also struggling with it :(

Comment: Hey @BadmusTaofeeq, I wasn't able to fix the nginx error. I created a laradock with apache instead of nginx. Not a real fix but I already lost too much time to investigate this further.

Comment: oh, nice, i'll do this aswell. thanks. seems to be working for some guys. I really want to know why it wouldn't work. want to check it together?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

The issue was in my mistake in parameter "root" in nginx's [your-name].conf file.

It should match the path shown when you log in the laradock "workspace" (with "docker-compose exec workspace bash"), e.g. "/var/www".

In your case it looks like should be string

root /var/www/public

instead of

root /var/www/example/public

Answer (score 0):

The error occured because of invalid naming in laradock/nginx/sites/

```
before: laradock/nginx/sites/domain.laravel

after: laradock/nginx/sites/domain.laravel.conf
```

worked for me!